# How to process request and do not return anything in spring

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am sending ajax request to spring controller from dialog box. The request is processed correctly, but after that dialog box is get closed and page is redirected to the url send in request.
I tried @RequestStatus(HttpStatus.OK) to not send any view name. Still page gets refreshed.

What I want is to remain dialog box open which sends request and page should not get refreshed.

Comment: For methods that return a String view name, you can return null. This will tell Spring you have already generated the response yourself. Alternatively, check out the `@ResponseBody` annotation for handler methods.

Comment: Please add some code, exactly how are you making the ajax call? With an ajax call, whether the page is refreshed or not is decided on the front end, it has nothing to do with what the server returns.